# Assigning increasing integer numbers to distinct values that share identical values in the previous columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that goes like this

| Index | One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | - | - | - | - | - |
| 2 | A | B | C | - | - | - |
| 3 | A | B | C | F | L | - |
| 4 | A | B | C | F | M | S |
| 5 | A | B | D | G | N | - |
| 6 | A | B | D | H | O | - |
| 7 | A | B | D | I | P | T |
| 8 | A | B | E | J | Q | - |
| 9 | A | B | E | K | R | U |

And I would like an output like the following where the distinct identifiers (that builds on top of the combinations of the previous columns) are assigned an increasing integer number for each distinct value:

- Column "One" has only 1 distinct ("A") identifier so all of them are substituted by the integer 1.
- Column "Two" has 2 distinct identifiers "-" and "B" (this works as a regular pd.Categorical because they all share the same value in column "One")
- Column "Three" is where things get tricky for me. Row index 1 gets 1 because the "-" is the only distinct identifier for the combination ("A","-" the two previous columns "One" and "Two"). Row index 2, 3 and 4 gets 1 as well because "C" is the first distinct identifier for the combination ("A","B" coming respectively from column "One" and "Two"). Row 5, 6, 7 gets 2, because "D" is the second distinct identifier for the combination "A","B" etc...
- Last example row 3 and 4, column "Five". They got value 1 and 2 because they share the same path (A,B,C,F) until column "Four" but in column "Five" they got distinct values (L and M).

| Index | One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Apologies for the small essay.
And thanks for your help.
I tried to loop over multiples groupby but I got lost in it.

Regards,
Dario

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Why do `'-'` and `'C'` in column `'Three'` both receive the same identifier `1`?

Comment: Yeah.  This makes no sense.  The behavior of '-' in each of the columns seems completely different.

Comment: seems like a mistake column Three, Row 2,3,4 should be 2 not 1

Comment: In column "Three", row 1, "-" is the first unique identifier that has the previous path (comibation) "A" and "-" in column One and Two respectively. "C" in row 2,3,4 get 1 as well because it's the first identifier for the combination "A" "B" in column one and two.

Comment: So, if a value is present in the same row in previous columns it gets the same as if the value has not occurred yet? That doesn't make any sense. I also do not understand why B in 'Two' gets 2, then. Looking at it again, it seems that you are considering both previous values in the ROW as well as the COL the value is in. So,  [2, Two] is 2 because B is the second unique value in col 2, and has not been assigned an ID in column One. Is that your logic?

Comment: No column Six is all 1's. Okay I give up sorry, this is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need to perform successive [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) using the previous column as grouper:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)

out[df.columns[0]] = df.groupby(df.columns[0]).ngroup().add(1)

for i in range(1, df.shape[1]):
    out[df.columns[i]] = (df
  .groupby(df.columns[i-1], group_keys=False)
  .apply(lambda g: g.groupby(df.columns[i]).ngroup().add(1)).squeeze()
)

print(out)
```

If you need to group by all previous columns, change the loop to:

```
for i in range(1, df.shape[1]):
    out[df.columns[i]] = (df
  .groupby(list(df.columns[:i]), group_keys=False)
  .apply(lambda g: g.groupby(df.columns[i]).ngroup().add(1)).squeeze()
)
```

Output:

```
       One  Two  Three  Four  Five  Six
Index                                  
1        1    1      1     1     1    1
2        1    2      1     1     1    1
3        1    2      1     2     1    1
4        1    2      1     2     2    1
5        1    2      2     1     1    1
6        1    2      2     2     1    1
7        1    2      2     3     1    1
8        1    2      3     1     1    1
9        1    2      3     2     1    1
```

Comment: It's all previous columns. I'll test this tomorrow. Thanks mate you are an absolute legend.

Comment: Mate, really appreciate this. I got a follow-up question. The result is flowless but, is there a way to have 0 (zero) instead of 1 when the values is '-'? Everything else should look exactly the same, same logic, E.g. Column two should be 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 and column six 0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1

Comment: The easiest, to keep the original code, would be to mask: `out = out.mask(df.eq('-'), 0)`

Comment: That works mate, I know have a "2" without a "1" as unique identifier for some columns but honestly it does the work. Thanks again mate.